# Python formatting my json output

Tags: python, json, formatting, output, pprint

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import json
from pprint import pprint

drink_list = [23,601,633,673,607,662,6622,6014,6104,615,038,606,607,627,6094]

filename = (r'C:\Users\desktop\pizza\123template.json')

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

try:
    template = json.loads(data)
except Exception:
    # this file can also be here 
    print('json exception')
    raise


for output in drink_list:
    print(output)
    temp = template.copy()
    temp["meta"]["sodanumber"] = output


    with open(r'C:\Users\desktop\pizza\123\{}.json'.format(output, indent=40), 'w', encoding='cp1252') as f:
        data = json.dumps(temp)
        f.write(data)
       # pprint.pprint(temp, width=60)
```

IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level.

But I think it's more than a simple indention. I can get my console to change formatting, but need the formatting to be changed in the actual output file. But where would I add my additional formatting to my "with open" line?

Have been reading material for 4 hours on this, and simple examples, but does the pprint do most of the work?

Current output is tons of work-wrapped text. Output needs to look like below. How can I get it to look like this?:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "drinkNumber": 662,
        "effectiveDate": "2016-10-12 16:00:31",
        "documentType": "checkout-device"
    },
    "documents": [
        {
            "code": "Checkout2",
            "name": "Printer 2",
            "port": "COM2",
            "type": "LABEL",
```

Current Output:

```
{ "meta": { "drinkNumber": 662, "effectiveDate": "2016-10-12 16:00:31", "documentType": "checkout-device" },"documents": [{
"code": "Checkout2","name": "Printer 2","port": "COM2","type": "LABEL",
```

Comment: could you provide an example of your actual output with the question? preferably with the same values as your "desired format" example.

Comment: @FloMei updated with current output

Comment: This is two completely different and unrelated problems in one. The fact that you got an `IndentationError` from the **Python source code** has **nothing to do with** the problem of indenting the JSON output.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

data = { "meta": { "drinkNumber": 662, "effectiveDate": "2016-10-12 16:00:31", "documentType": "checkout-device" },"documents": [{ "code": "Checkout2","name": "Printer 2","port": "COM2","type": "LABEL"}]}

json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Output:

```
{
    "documents": [
        {
            "code": "Checkout2",
            "name": "Printer 2",
            "port": "COM2",
            "type": "LABEL"
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "documentType": "checkout-device",
        "drinkNumber": 662,
        "effectiveDate": "2016-10-12 16:00:31"
    }
}
```

**Note**: your current output is not complete.

Comment: Thanks I'll have to review this when I have a moment. I appreciate the help!